# Will the file be in the bucket by the time the pickAndStore success callback is called?

Tags: filepicker.io

We recently enabled S3 storage on our Filepicker.io account. I was wondering if the success callback of the `pickAndStore` method is called after the file has been completely copied to the bucket. This seems to be the case, but I just wanted to confirm this because it is not clearly stated in the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right. PickAndStore and store success callbacks are called after files is completly copied.

The success callback returns also s3 key and container.
Here is sample response:

```
{
   "url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/HRZVLkUCT12s7FZS5HGP",
   "filename":"logo.png",
   "mimetype":"image/png",
   "size":37913,
   "key":"pKSNXswMTqOYOi9J1JHY_logo.png",
   "container":"kg_bucket",
   "isWriteable":true
}
```

Beside filepicker filelink you can use s3 link directly.

- key - the S3 key where we have stored the file.
- container - which is name of bucket where the file is stored.

Url to your S3 file:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/your_bucket_name/your_file_key.txt

https://s3.amazonaws.com/kg_bucket/pKSNXswMTqOYOi9J1JHY_logo.png